# Difficulties computing the reduced groebner basis

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

I have the polynomials $f_1 = - x^2 + y^2 + 20$, $f_2 = xy -y^2 + 20$ and want to compute the reduced groebner basis of $I = \langle f_1,f_2 \rangle$ regarding $lex$ ordering. I computed the S-Polynomial and $S(f_1,f_2) \equiv 0 \mod I$ so that $I$ is really a groebner basis. Now I tried to compute the minimal groebner basis. Multiplying $f_1$ by $-1$ leads to $f_1 = x^2 - y^2 - 20$ so that I have $LC(f_1)=LC(f_2)=1$.

When I look at the leading monomials than there is nothing to "remove" because $x^2 \nmid xy$ and $xy \nmid x^2$ so that I already have the minimal groebner basis.

So now I want to compute the reduced one. Therefore I computed the following:

$1.Step:\;I_1 = \langle h_1,f_2 \rangle,\quad h_1 = f_1 \mod f_2$
$2.Step:\;I_2 = \langle h_1,h_2 \rangle,\quad h_2 = f_2 \mod h_2$

Then $I_2 = \langle x^2 - xy - 40, x^2 - y^2 - 20 \rangle$ should have been reduced but somehow it is not. Sage is telling me, that the reduced one is the following $I = \langle x + 2y, y^2 - 20/3 \rangle$

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: What do you mean by $S(f_1,f_2)\equiv 0\mod I$ ? It is clear that in the quotient space $\pmod I$ the S-polynomial is $0$ (because it is always, by construction, an element of $I$), but the matter is whether it *reduces* to $0$ through the generalised division by the sequence $f_1,f_2$. For instance, here I see $$S(f_1,f_2)=-xy^2+20x+y^3+20y=\\ =0\cdot f_1-y\cdot f_2+20x+40y$$ and therefore $S(f_1,f_2)$ reduces, essentially, to $x+2y$.

Comment: You helped me a lot, thank you. I misunderstood the .reduce() function in Sage. I thought, that it does the generalised division by $f_1,f_2$ but it does not. It seems that it always gives you the unique remainder, as if your ideal was generated by a groebner basis and of course that is not what i wanted here. it's exactly how you say, I get $S(f_1,f_2) \mod I$ and not the remainder by generalised division.Now everything ist clear